# After 13.10 install none of my apps appear in the Dashboard, only social network apps (of which I have none)

Tags: unity-dash, system-installation

After 13.10 installation none of my apps appear on the Dashboard so effectively I cannot launch any apps from the Dash only through the terminal.

[image]

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

I would ensure all of these were installed:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-lens-applications unity-lens-files unity-lens-music unity-lens-video
```

if that works, great. Otherwise also try:

```
rm ~/.cache/software-center -R
```

and

```
unity --reset &
```

Edit: it as pointed out in the comments:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-scope-home
```

may also solve the issue. Thanks

Comment: I have this exact problem, but it may have happened before 13.10.  None of those suggestions did anything, and the last one is deprecated.

Comment: I fixed mine with this command: `sudo apt-get install unity-scope-home`